# 'DataLoader' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch, imagenet

I have downloaded the ImageNet dataset via this pytorch api by setting download=True. But I cannot iterate through the dataloader.

The error says "'DataLoader' object does not support indexing"

```
trainset = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    datasets.ImageNet('/media/farshid/DataStore/temp/Imagenet/', split='train',
                      download=False))
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, num_workers=1)
```

I tried a simple approach I just tried to run the following,

```
trainloader[0]
```

In the root directory, the pattern is

```
root/  
    train/  
          n01440764/
          n01443537/ 
                   n01443537_2.jpg
```

The docs in the official website doesnt say anything else. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/datasets.html#imagenet

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You are creating `DataLoader` from `DataLoader` in your example, is it a mistake or your real code?

Comment: Yes that is the real code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution

```
input_transform = standard_transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((255,255)), # to Make sure all the 
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),   # imgs are at the same size 
    transforms.ToTensor()
])  


# torch.utils.data.Dataset object
trainset = datasets.ImageNet('/media/farshid/DataStore/temp/Imagenet/',
                             split='train', download=False, transform = input_transform)
# torch.utils.data.DataLoader object
trainloader =torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=2, shuffle=False)


for batch_idx, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
    x, y = data 
    break
```

Answer (score 9):

Well, the answer is pretty simple (besides error mentioned in the other answer).

**`DataLoader` has no `__getitem__` method** (see [in the source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/data/dataloader.html#DataLoader) for yourself).

It is used for iterating, not random access, over data (or batches of data). If you want to access specific element you should use `torch.utils.data.Dataset`, in your case:

```
trainset = torchvision.datasets.ImageNet('/media/farshid/DataStore/temp/Imagenet/', split='train', )
trainset[0]
```

### Getting a batch

If you want to get a batch you may iterate over it and break afterwards:

```
for batch in dataloader:
    print(batch) # or anything else you want to do
    break
```

`DataLoader` creates random indices in default or specified way (see [samplers](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.SequentialSampler)), hence there is no `__getitem__` as it wouldn't make sense for this object.

You may also inherit from the `DataLoader` and create your own `__getitem__` function doing what you want (more complicated though).

### Full example

```
# torch.utils.data.Dataset object
trainset = datasets.ImageNet('/media/farshid/DataStore/temp/Imagenet/', split='train', download=True)
# torch.utils.data.DataLoader object
trainloader =torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)

for batch in trainloader:
    print(batch)
    break
```

Above should print the first batch whatever is inside.

Comment: Then how do I get it like a batch ?

Comment: Just to clarify, what do you mean by 'dataloader' according to Anubhav Singh's code is it the 'trainset' or 'trainloader' ? Cause with trainloader it doesnt work !

Comment: It works if you create `DataLoader` from `train_dataset`. `dataloader` refers to instance of such `DataLoader` class.

Comment: I am really getting confused here. Can you please explain or just update your codes

Comment: Well yes and no. The problem I was facing was the img being a PIL file and the debugger doesnt say it. Your code still doesnt run without errors. The fix is add "standard_transforms.ToTensor()," as transforms. :)

Comment: Plus for some reason increasing the batch size from 1 to anything else doesnt work

Comment: Yeah, I assumed correct transformations and `print` is a simple example to get the point across.

Answer (score 1):

The input dataset to `torch.utils.data.DataLoader()` should be of type `torch.utils.data.Dataset`, not `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`, which is what you are doing in above code.

So, your above code should be:

```
trainset = torchvision.datasets.ImageNet('/media/farshid/DataStore/temp/Imagenet/', 
                                          split='train', 
                                          download=False)

trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, 
                                          batch_size=1, 
                                          shuffle=False, 
                                          num_workers=1)
```

For more details, check the official torch documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/datasets.html#imagefolder).

Comment: Yes I see the problem and I tried your solution. I still have the same error "'DataLoader' object does not support indexing" when I do "trainloader[0]"

Comment: While true, it does not solve the issue (leaving alone the fact of reiterating the comment).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this dirty solution:

```
def Dataloader_by_Index(data_loader, target=0):
    for index, data in enumerate(data_loader):
        if index == target:
            return data
    return None
fifth_element = Dataloader_by_Index(my_data_loader, target=4)
```