# How can I access the next step data using DataLoader in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, dataloader

I am using a code that trains neural networks. The code uses the DataLoader of PyTorch to load the data for every iteration. The code looks as follows

```
for step, data in enumerate(dataloader, 0):
      ............................................................
      output = neuralnetwork_model(data)
      .............................................................
```

Here the step is an integer that gives values 0, 1, 2, 3, ....... and data gives a batch of samples at each step. The code passes corresponding batches to the neural network at each step.

I need to just access the data of step n+1 at step n. I need something like this

```
for step, data in enumerate(dataloader, 0):
      ............................................................
      output = neuralnetwork_model(data)
      access = data_of_next_step
      .............................................................
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could always save the previous batch on a variable and process the current batch with the n-1.

Comment: You can use `next`, but it will advance the iterator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585405/is-calling-nextiter-inside-for-i-in-iter-supported-in-python

You can subclass DataLoader and implement a `__getitem__` to allow using `step + 1` as index: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838341/dataloader-object-does-not-support-indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be handier to perform such manipulation at the iteration level rather than having to change the data loaders implementation. Looking at [*Iterate over `n` successive elements with overlap*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38151585/6331369) you can achieve this using [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee):

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

Therefore you simply have to iterate over your wrapped data loader with:

```
>>> for batch1, batch2 pairwise(dataloader)
...     # batch1 is current batch
...     # batch2 is batch of following step
```